# Buffer and Intersect differences

Tags: buffer

“What is the difference between ‘Select by location using a buffer or intersection’ and the ‘Buffer’ or ‘Intersect’ Analysis tools?

Comment: What software are you using?

Answer (score 7):

If you are referring to the tools in ArcGIS, then one difference is that using the tool provides an output dataset, whereas Select by Location does not.